# jquery access to my server host var?

Tags: jquery

is it possible to use

```
$.post("/home/ACOUNT_NAME/ACOUNT_DOMAIN/script.php")
```

to access a php file outside the main domain BUT on the same webserver?

with php I can do that, wich is very good since I need to use the same file in many domains.

Now I need to have access to the same file but using jquery, but browser doesn't go there, he always uses

> domain/home/ACOUNT_NAME/ACOUNT_DOMAIN/script.php

any sugestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript **cannot** access server files.

You can try to post to a php file that is in the domain which would then read from that server file and output it to the user.

Comment: You may be wright, I tryed that and it seems to be possible, for now I'm just getting ï»¿ as result, but it may work

Comment: Hello, same thing, different context, I'm using one php file to upload pictures, it works very well, but i've it in my subdomain, serving some domains on my server. how can I read the innerHTML of  the created iframe from my domains? I got a security issue...

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696612/jquery-upload-read-innerhtml-from-external-domain-on-same-webserver