# jquery upload read innerHTML from external domain on same webserver

Tags: jquery, upload

I've one php file on mysubdomain and want to use that script to manage uploads for all my domains (all reside on same webserver)

I use

```
var resposta = document.getElementById('iframe_uploads').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

but I get this error

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

My questio is, is there a way I can read the inneHTML from this Iframe?

it returns this

```
ok|image.gif|458=458
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which requires that domain and protocol must match.

**Quoting:**

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.

Take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to work around it.

Comment: hello, thanks for reply. that sounds dangerous... everything is working good, just needed to receive some kind of action to remove my upload modal from stage. I think I will need to have one upload php file on each domain. :-(